# What happens if the image of a set is empty?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone give me hint how to prove that for a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $B\subseteq X$ we have $$f(B)=\emptyset \Rightarrow B=\emptyset \ ?$$

Is my idea that, supposing $x\in B\neq \emptyset$, we would have to have, since $f$ is a function, a $y$ such that $f(x)=y$ and therefore $y\in f(B)=\emptyset$, which is a contradiction, correct ?

Comment: You don't need a hint; that is a correct proof.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: You can cast it as a proof by contrapositive (which it is) instead of a proof by contradiction: $B\neq\varnothing\implies f(B)\neq\varnothing$.

Comment: Correct proof. Try formalizing it more though.

Comment: Thanks. Although, now I'm observing that I actually wasn't precise enough: $Y$ is not allowed to be the empty set. Otherwise we wouldn't even have a function $f$ to talk about, right ?

Comment: $Y$ can be the empty set if $X$ is also.

Comment: Perhaps it worth noting that we can construct "apparent" counterexamples that are not really counterexamples.  Consider f(x) = 1/x.  Many sets have nice images, e.g., f([1,2]) = [1/2,1] and f({3}) = {1/3}.  However, should we say that f({0}) = {}?  In this case we seem to have a non-empty set with an empty image.  The resolution, of course, is that f was never defined on 0, and so that should never be counted, any more than asking what is f({cat,dog,mouse}) when f(x)=1/x, which I guess would be the empty set in the same sense.  Similarly if f(x) = sqrt(x) if B is the set of negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Hard to beat that for concision.

Comment: But comments must be at least 15 characters long...

Comment: And answers have to be at least $40$. But those excess characters don't have to actually end up displaying anything.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly longer answer. :-)

A straightforward calculation shows that both parts are actually equivalent: we start with the left hand side, expand the definition of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$, and then simplify.
\begin{align}
& f[B] = \varnothing \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"basic property of empty set"} \\
& \langle \forall y :: y \not\in f[B] \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y :: \lnot \langle \exists x : x \in B : f(x) = y \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify: apply DeMorgan to $\;\exists x\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall y :: \langle \forall x : x \in B : f(x) \not= y \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"rearrange quantifications -- to prepare for one-point rule"} \\
& \langle \forall x,y : y = f(x) : x \not\in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"one-point rule"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \not\in B \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"basic property of empty set"} \\
& B = \varnothing \\
\end{align}